# Importing a scanner class in a method

Tags: java

I have this assignment in school, where I have to import a scanner and write a method. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       applicationDate();

     }
     public static void applicationDate()
     {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("On what day of the month you applied?");

        int day = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is the name of the month in wich you applied?");

        String month = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("During wich year you applied?");

        int year = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Your application date is" + month + " ", + year + "!");

      }
```

It comes with this error when I compile the thing,
EX20.java:27: cannot find symbol

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace message to help you spot the problem. Also, it will help to know which line is number 27.

Comment: @Smutje when the compiler doesn't know which class you're using, it throws a different error: *`Scanner` cannot be resolved to a type*. But from the error description, the error is *cannot find symbol* which means an undefined variable.

Comment: I'd just like to note that `day` is not used.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no, that's not true. When I compile

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l;   
    }
}

the compiler says "Main.java:4: error: cannot find symbol".

Comment: @Smutje yes, right. Tested it on my IDE and give me a different compiler error =\. Retested it using plain old javac and I get that compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove comma and add it in between double quotes like below.

```
  System.out.print("Your application date is" + month + " ,"+ year + "!");
```

Comment: How does this differ from the existing answer?

Comment: @JoshM the comma is part of the String, in the other answer you just removed it...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ah, I see.

Answer (score 3):

`print` only takes one `String` argument - move the comma inside the `String`

```
System.out.print("Your application date is" + month + " ," + year + "!");
                                                        ^
```

Comment: Now you take out the *grace* to see OP learning to learn how to spot the problem. Anyway, +1.

Comment: +1 Wow, nice eyes. : ) Also, I think `System.out.printf("Your application date is %s, %d!", month, year);` looks more neat.

Comment: @tinaw25 The `error: cannot find symbol` was occurring because you are not importing `Scanner`. The `extra comma` problem was second.

Answer (score 1):

First add `import java.util.Scanner;` to your file.
As this line is missing you must be getting error as

```
error: cannot find symbol
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ^
```

then

Remove extra comma from the last print statement.

```
System.out.print("Your application date is" + month + " ,"+ year + "!");
```